# React Native unrecognized event and metro server not working

Tags: android, express, expo, react-native

I am trying to set up Android Studio with expo on a linuxmint OS, though it has proven difficult since it has these issues.

First I get:

```
Unrecognized event: {"type":"client_log","level":"log","data":["Running \"main\" with {\"initialProps\":{\"exp\":{\"initialUri\":\"exp://jz-c4q.anonymous.exp.direct:80\",\"manifest\":{\"iconUrl\":\"http://packager.jz-c4q.anonymous.exp.direct:80/assets/./assets/images/icon.png\",\"version\":\"1.0.0\",\"xde\":true,\"updates\":{\"fallbackToCacheTimeout\":0},\"sdkVersion\":\"38.0.0\",\"platforms\":[\"android\",\"ios\"],\"hostUri\":\"jz-c4q.anonymous.exp.direct:80\",\"slug\":\"\",\"icon\":\"./assets/images/icon.png\",\"web\":{\"favicon\":\"./assets/images/favicon.png\"},\"loadedFromCache\":false,\"debuggerHost\":\"packager.jz-c4q.anonymous.exp.direct:80\",\"splash\":{\"resizeMode\":\"contain\",\"backgroundColor\":\"#ffffff\",\"image\":\"./assets/images/splash.png\",\"imageUrl\":\"http://packager.jz-c4q.anonymous.exp.direct:80/assets/./assets/images/splash.png\"},\"primaryColor\":\"#023C69\",\"orientation\":\"portrait\",\"isVerified\":true,\"env\":{},\"id\":\"@anonymous/-7a7930a8-81c8-493d-a666-abe1c7df80c5\",\"scheme\":\"myapp\",\"bundleUrl\":\"http://packager.jz-c4q.anonymous.exp.direct:80/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false\",\"packagerOpts\":{\"https\":false,\"dev\":true,\"lanType\":\"ip\",\"hostType\":\"tunnel\",\"minify\":false,\"urlRandomness\":\"jz-c4q\"},\"name\":\"\",\"ios\":{\"supportsTablet\":true},\"developer\":{\"tool\":\"expo-cli\",\"projectRoot\":\"/home/\"},\"mainModuleName\":\"node_modules/expo/AppEntry\",\"logUrl\":\"http://jz-c4q.anonymous.exp.direct:80/logs\",\"assetBundlePatterns\":[\"**/*\"],\"userInterfaceStyle\":\"automatic\"},\"shell\":false}},\"rootTag\":41}"]}
```

Then I get: `Unrecognized event: {"type":"client_log","level":"log","data":["[Error: Network Error]"]}`

When I ran it previously on a windows machine I didn't have this issue.

I also get an error regarding the metro server, when all errors have been presented: `Cannot connect to the Metro server`.

I tried as well setting up a new react native project, and it seemed to work fine there, might there  be something wrong with the backend?

Any idea of what might be going wrong here, and what may fix the issues?

Answer (score 1):

This problem was resolved for me when I upgraded the expo-cli.